# Not showing extract string resource in android studio 3.3.2

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I have created a new project in kotline in android studio 3.3.2 and now I am not getting few default settings as it was before. Like attribute window is not showing populer attributes in default-

[image: empty default attribute window]

And not getting extract string resource option as below -

[image: options for hardcoded string in layout xml file]

Any help would be appreciable.

Here is my build-

[image: build.gradle]

Comment: Just restart you studio may be It have cache. Because It is snowing on android studio and I have a same version .

Comment: I have restarted many times and also use clear cache and restart option in file menu.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu please do not add tags that have nothing to do with the question. And remember - tag by content, **not** by context. This is about the editor itself and has nothing to do with Kotlin, even though there's a Kotlin activity

Answer (score 1):

Add `package="com.example.app"` to your `Manifest.xml` file's root tag (`<manifest>`) if it does not exist (Replace "com.example.app" with your own package).

Answer (score 0):

You should restart you android studio for the problem of attribute window.

For the problem of `extract string resource option` not found, maybe you have it disabled and you can activate it like this

1. Click Help
2. Find Action
3. Search for "Extract string resource"
4. Check if it is Off just click on.

Comment: I have restarted android studio many times and also checked the option in find action and its on.

Comment: does build.gradle file can make any difference on behaviour of android studio functions.

Comment: yes if support design library is instable or old you can have this type of malfunction

Answer (score 0):

Go buil.gradle and
Change SDK 33 to 32

Delete cache folder, renaming catch folder won't work
Do it and enjoy coding

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This operation is enabled by default.
press alt+enter on value 
sample :
String  a="Aa";
you must press alt+enter  when cursor on "Aa" value